# React event delegation - unexpected redirection to the root path

Tags: reactjs, events, event-delegation

I wrote a React component below and observed weird behavior. All of Button-B,C,D works as expected, executing the function specified in the onClick, but only the Button-A do not. If I click Button-A, it redirects me to the root path without any output to the console. Could someone help me to understand what is happening here and how I can make Button-A work, meaning assign the click event to a function I defined in the component? I assume this relates to the React event delegation but could not identify the root cause and how to solve. Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import uuid from "react-uuid"

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faSquarePlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import "./Create.css"

function CreateOld() {
  const [tickers, setTickers] = useState([{id: uuid(), ticker: "", ratio: ""}]);

  const addTicker = () => {
    console.log("add ticker pressed")
    const newTicker = {
      id: uuid(),
      ticker: "",
      ratio: "",
    }
    setTickers([...tickers, newTicker])
    console.log(tickers);
  }

  const onUpdateTicker = (updatedTicker) => {
    const updatedTickersArray = tickers.map((ticker) => {
      if (ticker.id === updatedTicker.id){
        return updatedTicker;
      } else {
        return ticker;
      }
    });
    setTickers(updatedTickersArray);
  }

  const onEditTicker = (ticker, key, value) => {
    onUpdateTicker({
      ...ticker,
      [key]: value,
    })
  };

  const clickHandlerA = () => {
    console.log('Clicked Button-A');
  };

  const clickHandlerB = () => {
    console.log('Clicked Button-B');
  };

  const clickHandlerC = () => {
    console.log('Clicked Button-C');
  };

  const clickHandlerD = () => {
    console.log('Clicked Button-D');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>

        <div>
          <button type="button" className='createButton' id="button-A" onClick={clickHandlerA}>
            Button-A
          </button>
        </div>

        <div>
          {errorMessage && <div className='error-message'>{errorMessage}</div>}
        </div>

        <div>
        {tickers.map((ticker,index)=>(

            <div className="tickerContainer" key={ticker.id} id={ticker.id}>
              <div className="inputPortfolio">
                <div>Ticker</div>
                <input type="text" placeholder='Ticker' value={ticker.ticker} onChange={(e) => onEditTicker(ticker, "ticker", e.target.value)}/>
              </div>
              <div className="inputPortfolio">
                <div>Unit/Unit Ratio</div>
                  <input type="text" placeholder='Unit/Unit Ratio'  value={ticker.ratio} onChange={(e) => onEditTicker(ticker, "ratio", e.target.value)}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          
          ))}
        </div>

        <div className="addTickerButton">
        <button type="button" className='createTickerButton' id="addTickerButton" onClick={addTicker}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquarePlus} />Button-B
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" className='createButton' id="button-B" onClick={clickHandlerC}>
          Button-C
        </button>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div className="createPortfolioButton">
        <button type="button" className='createButton'  id="createPortfolioButton" onClick={clickHandlerD}>
          Button-D
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CreateOld
```

I expected to execute clickHandlerA when I clicked Button-A.
Also, I tried to add e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() but none of them did not solve the problem.

Parent Component App.jsx

```
import Nabvar from './components/Navbar'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Portfolio from './components/Portfolio'
import NewPortfolio from './components/NewPortfolio'

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"


function App() {  
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Nabvar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}></Route>
          <Route path="/new" element={<NewPortfolio/>}></Route>
          <Route path="/portfolio/:portfolio_id" element={<Portfolio/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of (ancient) HTML5 semantics around forms. I'm guessing some parent component wraps all of this in a `<form>`. The first button inside a form is assigned as the submit button by default in HTML5. When you submit a form, the `onSubmit` is called on that `<form>`. If no such handler is present, it does the browser default which is to `POST` the form contents to the current URL. It'll also do that if there *is* a handler but there's no `e.preventDefault()`.

Your code doesn't show the parent, but you should add an `onSubmit` prop to the `form` if there isn't one and *then* call `e.preventDefault()` in *that* handler. If there already is one, add the `e.preventDefault()` to the top of it.

Comment: Hi adsy, big thanks for your comment. Actually, the parent does not have the explicit <form> as you can see the code of parent I added above, App.jsx. Do one of <Router> and <Routes> work as <form>? Adding onSubmit={(e)=>(e.preventDefault())} to them did not work. Any other possible cause of this?

Comment: If there isnt one, you need to add one in and then put the `onSubmit` handler on it.